# Flutter, Hive and iCloud

Tags: flutter, hive, icloud

Hi I have an established app and my users are requesting the ability to sync data between devices. I’m currently using hive to store data locally. Is it possible to use iCloud to sync the hive box? Or should I just rework with firebase?

Comment: use FireBase :)